# AWS MQTT broker scaling issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am using AWS IoT in my cloud application.

I have created IoT rules and lambda functions to process the MQTT publish messages.

When the MQTT Client publishes the message to a topic, a rule is triggered and a lambda function is executed.

While carrying out the load testing, I found that, after some time, MQTT broker doesn’t process the messages.

On the AWS IoT ( monitor ) console, I can see the number of successful connections reaching to 400.

My MQTT clients are opening around 50 connections, publishing the message and waiting for async response on another topic for 60 seconds.

After receiving the response or 60 seconds timeout, these connections are closed. 
Then next set of 50 connection requests are made to AWS MQTT broker.

The client is developed using AWSIoTPythonSDK.

I  don’t see any errors  in the IOT console as well as in the Lambda monitoring console.

Also I don’t see any message or log, which says the request are throttled.

I have raised a request to increase the limit for number Connect Requests Per Second to 1000.

Is there any way to find out, if the MQTT broker is throttling the request or if there are any other errors?

Answer (score 0):

Following url is about aws iot limits.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_iot

Did you turn on aws iot log(debug level or info level)? And Can you see connection logs in cloudWatch?